# How can I solve identifiability problems in my STAN estimation?

Tags: bayesian, stan, item-response-theory, identifiability, uninformative-prior

So I am trying to validate my STAN model before using real data and am having some trouble estimating parameters separately. My data structure contains count data with people on the rows, and test items in the columns. I am trying to use a covariate for item type, for example multiple choice, and see how this affects my difficulty parameters. Normally, I would just have the following:

```
   for(i in 1:n_examinee){
     for (j in 1:n_item){
       lambdas[i,j] = exp(theta[i] + raw_difficulty [j]);
       target += poisson_lpmf(Y[i,j] | lambdas[i,j]);
     }
```

With the addition of the covariate on the item difficulty we now have:

```
  for (i in 1:n_item) {
    item_difficulty[i] = raw_difficulty [i] + dot_product(X[i], beta_difficulty);
  }
   for(i in 1:n_examinee){
     for (j in 1:n_item){
       lambdas[i,j] = exp(theta[i] + item_difficulty[j]);
       target += poisson_lpmf(Y[i,j] | lambdas[i,j]);
     }
```

In this case X[i] refers to the row of a dummy matrix containing item types, indicating which items are which type. This matrix also had a column removed to use as a reference category. Beta difficulty are the covariate estimates for the remaining covariates in X.
So for example the first item may be item_difficulty[1] = .3 + [1,0] * [-.25,.63]. However, when comparing my estimates against my true parameters it is clear there are identifiability problems.My estimates for raw_difficulty and beta_difficulty are not near their respective true values, however, their sum, item_difficulty is. Which logically makes sense as there are infinite values that could satisfy the equation.

What can I do to solve this problem? While item_difficulty matches the true values, I want to be able to tell how severe the effects of the item type are, so I would need to have reliable beta_difficulty estimates. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Two- and three-parameter IRT models have indeterminacies of location and scale, which generally [require informative priors](https://mc-stan.org/docs/stan-users-guide/priors-for-identification.html). This will extend to your additional covariates as well. Did you set priors and if so which?

Comment: The identifiability constraint is inherent to the specified model, not to the estimation procedure, ie. the "true" parameters are identifiable only up to a constant. This is going to be the case for your real data too. You should take this into account when you compare the true and estimated values.

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously just add a constant to all the item difficulties on the log-scale and subtract the same constant from the `theta[i]` (and vice versa). This makes the model hard to sample (but if you manage that because the priors constrain things sufficiently to allow the NUTS sampler to sample it with a high enough `adapt_delta`, then relatively speaking everything is fine). Alternatively, you can introduce constraints (e.g. sum-to-zero constraints on the log-scale, or defining a reference category).